# How to make it right? - SQL Server Query

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table in my DB called Emplyee and contains these columns :

```
Categ - int
WorkPlace - int
WorkPlace1 - int
EducationalLevel - varchar(100)
System - varchar(100)
Type - varchar(100)
ApData - varchar(100)
```

I am making a search form and I don't know how to do this complicated query.

First the Categ is th main category and WorkPlace is sub category and WorkPlace1 is sub category for WorkPlace

I want to select all rows that match Categ and WorkPlace and WorkPlace1 and search for strings in other columns.

In other words, I want to search in these column EducationnalLevel, System, Type, ApData when there is match in the categories columns.

How I can do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to approach this (this assumes you define variables for all items starting with @):

```
declare @search varchar(100)
set @search = '%FIND_ME%'

select *
from Emplyee 
where Categ = @Categ and WorkPlace = @WorkPlace and WorkPlace1 = @WorkPlace1 and
(
   EducationalLevel like @search OR
   System like @search OR
   Type like @search OR
   ApData like @search
)
```